# Can I generate frequencies faster than 32 MHz with ATTINY85?

Tags: pwm, attiny, frequency

I believe I can use the 64 MHz PLL clock with PWM to toggle every cycle
and thereby generate a 32 MHz square wave output on an IO pin, right?

Is there a trick to generate an even higher frequency (with at least 1V
of swing) without needing external components?  For example, can I get
the 64 MHz PLL output itself off the chip?

Comment: Keep in mind that the 64 MHz PLL can only be referenced to the internal RC oscillator, not an external crystal.  So anything you do this way will be only approximately accurate in frequency.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to feed out a frequency higher than either the system clock frequency, or half the timer clock frequency (`PCLK/2`).

The system clock can be feed out by using the `CLKO` pin by setting the appropriate fuse as indicated in section 6.4. The highest system clock frequency possible (whilst remaining in-spec) is **16MHz**, which can be derived from either an external single-ended source, or in the case of the ATTiny85 from `PCLK/4` - the divide by 4 for the PLL can never be bypassed as indicated in Section 6.1.5. As discussed in the datasheet, it is not possible to to use `CLKO` when an external crystal is used.

Alternatively it is possible to use the timer to output a frequency of one half of the timer clock - by toggling the output each clock cycle. The highest frequency in-spec for the timer clock is 64MHz by using the 8x PLL from an 8MHz clock source (a 16MHz source can be used also by enabling the /2 pre-divider). This means the maximum frequency using Timer 1 is **32MHz**.

It is not possible to acheive a frequency higher than this without using external components, or operating the MCU outside of its rated specifications.

You could use a small external clock doubling circuit (e.g. XOR gate and delay chain) depending on how stable of a clock you require. Alternatively it may be simpler to provide a external clock source of the desired frequency - if you require some form of synchronisation, you could divide this higher frequency clock down to a frequency suitable for driving the MCUs `CLKI` pin.

Comment: Woops, missed how old this question was. It got bumped to the top by "Community" bot.

Answer (score -1):

According to the datasheet:

> **6.4 Clock Output Buffer**
>
> The device can output the system clock on the CLKO pin (when not used as XTAL2 
>   pin). To enable the output, the `CKOUT` Fuse has to be programmed. This mode is 
>   suitable when the chip clock is used to drive other circuits on the system. Note 
>   that the clock will not be output during reset and that the normal operation of 
>   the I/O pin will be overridden when the fuse is programmed. Internal RC 
>   oscillator, WDT Oscillator, PLL, and external clock (`CLKI`) can be selected when 
>   the clock is output on `CLKO`. Crystal oscillators (`XTAL1`, `XTAL2`) can not be used 
>   for clock output on `CLKO`. If the System Clock Prescaler is used, it is the 
>   divided system clock that is output.

So as long as you aren't using a crystal oscillator which would consume both the `CLKI` and `CLKO` pins you should be able to output the PLL's clock output directly through the `CLKO` pin.

Comment: But, the datasheet also says the chip always divides the PLL clock by 4 when using it for the system clock, so I think this technique would limit me to 16 MHz, right?  "There is an internal PLL that provides nominally 64 MHz clock rate locked to the RC Oscillator for the use of the Peripheral Timer/Counter1 and for the system clock source. When selected as a system clock source, by programming the CKSEL fuses to ‘0001’, it is divided by four like shown in Table 6-4."

Comment: I have never liked Atmel datasheets. It's very unclear, since in one place it says you can output the PLL (as one of a selection of items), and in others it says it's the system clock it outputs. It makes no sense. Just try it and see what you get I guess, since the datasheet is crap.

Comment: I'm using Digispark (and have already bricked 2 of my 4 units) without the normal serial programmer, so burning fuses isn't something I want to do unless I am sure it will work...but I might do so if answers here leave me uncertain.  Also, I don't have any equipment to check the output waveform frequency.

Comment: `in one place it says you can output the PLL (as one of a selection of items)` - In that excerpt it doesn't say that, it states that the system clock is output on the CLKO, and when enabled, only the RC, WDT, PLL and CLKI can be used as the source for the MCU clock. When the PLL is the source of the system clock, it always the PLL frequency /4 as shown in section 6.1.5.